# Assigning a Model Property to a textbox using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm unsure if this is possible but I want to use jQuery to assign value from my bound model to different textboxes inside a PartialView.

Originally when the page loads, it populates correctly with all of the model information. However I would like to implement a DDL to view historical updates (retrieved from my pre-populated DB).

I am able to call an Action method inside my respective controller which accepts a `revisionID`. I have verified that the method is returning the correct data.

Please see below for my code snippets:

**Partial View:**

```
$('#revisionDDL').change(function () {
    var selectedRevisionID = $(this).val();

    if (selectedRevisionID == '') {
        selectedRevisionID = @Model.RevisionID - 1;
    }

    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAgreementByRevision")';

    $.get(url, { revisionID: selectedRevisionID }, function () {
        $('#ChangeReason').val('@Model.ChangeReason');
    })
});
```

**Input element:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="change-reason">Change Reason</span>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ChangeReason, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "1" })
</div>
```

**Controller method:**

```
public ActionResult GetAgreementByRevision(int revisionID)
{
    Agreement revisedAgreement = new Agreement();

    revisedAgreement = _agreementService.GetAgreementDetailsByRevision(revisionID);

    return PartialView("AgreementDetailsFormPartial", revisedAgreement);
}
```

If I am not able to accomplish this, what would be my other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method in the controller returns `PartialView` which returns HTML content and you're trying to pass that HTML content as a value in the text area - this is not how it should work. You should return `Json(revisedAgreement, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and then access this object in JavaScript.

```
$.get(url, { revisionID: selectedRevisionID }, function (data) {
        // 'data' is your Agreement object
        $('#ChangeReason').val(data.SomePropertyHere);
    });
```

Comment: That works exactly how I want it to! Even though I've barely worked with JSON, a few quick documentation checks and everything is populating correctly. Thank you!